# Why are the output different for the same cout even if it one after another and for the same variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, std

Normal class to add Node to the list with push and pop action.

```
class listthis
    {
    private:
        struct Node {
            Node* next;
            int value;
        };
        Node* begin = nullptr;

    public:
        listthis(){
            Node newnode = Node();
            begin = &newnode;
        }

        void push(const int value){
            begin->value = value;
            begin->next = begin;
        }
```

when pop is called by the main function why is `cout` printing wrong ?

The pop function

```
        int pop(){
            std::cout<<begin->value<<"\n";
            std::cout<<begin->value<<"\n";
            std::cout<<begin->value<<"\n";
            std::cout<<begin->value<<"\n";
            std::cout<<begin->value<<"\n";
            int value = begin->value;
            begin->next = nullptr;
            return value;
        }

    };
```

The main function

```
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
        listthis t = listthis();
        t.push(1);
        t.pop();
        return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
    1  
    1  
    1  
    1  
    1952932600  
    1952932600
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Are you sure your `push()` implementation does anything reasonable?

Comment: Sorry but,  push() or my constructor doesn't seem to do anything but my question is not that but rather why is the cout printing "1952932600" value. And what is the reason for the same.

Answer (score 0):

This constructor

```
    listthis(){
        Node newnode = Node();
        begin = &newnode;
    }
```

is already wrong and has undefined behaviour because data member begin is assigned with the address of the local varaible newnode with automatic storage duration. After exiting the constructor the value of the pointer becomes invalid because the local variable will not be alive and the memory early iccupied by it can be overwritten.

It would be more logically consistent if the constructor and the member function push look like

```
    listthis() = default;

    void push( int value )
    {
        begin = new Node { begin, value };
    }
```

Take into account that

```
    void push( const int value );
```

and

```
    void push( int value );
```

declare the same one function though the definition of the function can depend on the qualifier of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your constructor to something like this;

```
listthis()
{
  begin = new Node();
}
```

Your complete class looks like this;

```
class listthis
    {
    private:
        struct Node {
            Node* next;
            int value;
        };
        Node* begin;

    public:
        listthis()
        {
            begin = new Node();
        }

        void push(const int value){
            begin->value = value;
            begin->next = begin;
        }

        int pop(){
            std::cout<<begin->value<<"\n";
            std::cout<<begin->value<<"\n";
            std::cout<<begin->value<<"\n";
            std::cout<<begin->value<<"\n";
            std::cout<<begin->value<<"\n";
            int value = begin->value;
            begin->next = nullptr;
            return value;
        }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> The correct constructor is :

```
listthis(){
            Node newnode = Node();
            begin = &newnode;
            begin->next = &newnode + sizeof(Node);
    }
```

> And the correct push is

```
void push(const T value){
        begin->next = begin + sizeof(Node);
        begin = begin->next;
        begin->value = value;
    }
```

But my question is why does pop print wrong or different value for "value" ?